# Heroku before_action :require_user, except: :auth being run for auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a simple before action which requires a user to be passed, though when authenticating I don't require it. Everything works locally, but when running the same tests (using postman) on the code that is up on heroku, I get the error associated with the `:require_user` method. I will write a simple example of what I'm trying to do below

```
before_action :require_user, except: [ :blah, :auth ]
def auth
    # do something and render appropriate json
end

private
def require_user
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
    return true if @user
    render json: { errors: 'Could not find user' }, status: 400
end
```

When I try to do the auth method on heroku, I get the `Could not find user` as the return value, which must mean it is hitting the require_user method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I figured it out... I was sending the post to `blah.heroku.com` instead of `blah.herokuapp.com` There is some redirect explained [1] which for some still unknown reason was messing up and running the before_action...

[1] https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h16-redirect-to-herokuapp-com